# Wicket Auth Roles Get Started

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, wicket

I need implement a Wicket App with the authentication and authorization concepts. This includes the restriction of actions to visual elements such as buttons and links.

I tried to find some example of `wicket-auth-roles` module, but the example access link on the official website is broken: [Wicket Auth/Roles](https://wicket.apache.org/learn/projects/authroles.html#example).

Someone would have any practical example of using this module?

Comment: The [link](http://wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/authorization) works for me.

Comment: @biziclop, thanks for reply! Did not see the link to the source code. Do you know if the roles may restrict buttons and/or links?

Comment: Well, in the examples they have [roles restricting labels](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/authorization/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?1&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.authorization.Index), so I would guess buttons and links should be possible too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check wicket-examples sub-module (deployed at http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/).
It has 4 examples of authentication and authorization.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I found the source code of these examples in the Apache Git repository: https://github.com/apache/wicket :)